# Are there any four-dimensional shapes in the whole wide world?

Tags: geometry, discrete-geometry

I've looked up images of a 4-D (four-dimensional) shape and they looked like there are built by using regular 3-D (three-dimensional) shapes using a regular 3-D shape connected to another 3-D shape inside of it using a string-like thing.  I'm wondering if there can be any 4-D shapes on Earth?  Are there any?  I'd like to hear your answers if you know what a 4-D shape is even by the help of what I just mentioned.  I'm here for you!

Comment: Even if there were, we would only be able to observe a 3D slice/projection of it. You can think of time as a dimension if you want, then everything exists as a long squiggly chain of itself throughout time.

Comment: While some theories in physics posit that there are more than three spatial dimensions, in everyday life we only see three of these dimensions (the rest are 'compactified').  However, if we represent a fourth spatial dimension in other ways, such as using color or brightness, we can emulate four-dimensional things; take for example the usual visualizations of Riemann surfaces.

Comment: What you have likely seen are projections of 4D-images into 3D space. And if you have seen (flat) images then those were again projected into 2D. A lot of this depends on your definitions. On the one hand, a 4D object can by definition not be embedded into 3D, so it can't exist there. On the other hand, many things are best modelled using more dimensions, so there are a lot of things for which a 4D description might make sense. But just because someone can describe something using 4D, does that mean that the thing is 4D? Or is just the description 4D, and that doesn't exist except in the mind?